# Playing a video from file using Microsoft Media Foundation

Tags: .net, ms-media-foundation

i am trying to use Windows Media Foundation to play a simple video.

unfortunately there seems to be little documentation on how to do this.

actually i am using the sharpDX binding to accomplish this. but i would be happy about C++ samples as well.

here is what i have so far trying to follow this tutorial
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms703190(v=vs.85).aspx

```
        MediaManager.Startup();

        MediaSession mediaSession;
        MediaFactory.CreateMediaSession(null, out mediaSession);

        SourceResolver sourceResolver;
        MediaFactory.CreateSourceResolver(out sourceResolver);

        ComObject comObject;
        ObjectType objectType;
        sourceResolver.CreateObjectFromURL("Jack.mp4", (int) SourceResolverFlags.None, null, out objectType, out comObject);

        Topology topology;
        MediaFactory.CreateTopology(out topology);
```

this runs without errors, but i havent figured out how to link this to a window or a texture so that i can actually see the video.

Answer (score 2):

Windows SDK has a number of [Media Foundation Samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371827%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (C++) in:

- \Samples\multimedia\mediafoundation

For example, [MFPlayer2 Sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd798738%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) creates player linking it to video window:

```
HRESULT MFPlayer2::Initialize(HWND hwndVideo)
{
   HRESULT hr = S_OK;

    SafeRelease(&m_pPlayer);

    hr = MFPCreateMediaPlayer(
        NULL,
        FALSE,          // Start playback automatically?
        0,              // Flags
        this,           // Callback pointer   
        hwndVideo,      // Video window
        &m_pPlayer
        );
```

Comment: It is, on the newer API (Media Session) you connect your windnow via `MFCreateVideoRendererActivate`, see [Creating Playback Topologies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms701605%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (at the bottom).

Comment: ..which is quite complicated and difficult to understand for me. all those topologies, streamdescriptors, sourceresolvers, etc...

Comment: This is where you switch to DirectShow API instead (which is not plain simple, but still way wider used).

Answer (score 2):

If you can drop support of Windows 7, use IMFMediaEngine instead of sessions.

[API documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/mfmediaengine/nn-mfmediaengine-imfmediaengine), [sample code](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/media-engine-playback-ce1c82f0).

Don't forget to add D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_VIDEO_SUPPORT [flag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/d3d11/ne-d3d11-d3d11_create_device_flag) to your D3D device, create [IMFDXGIDeviceManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/mfobjects/nn-mfobjects-imfdxgidevicemanager), and pass the manager to the engine in [MF_MEDIA_ENGINE_DXGI_MANAGER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/medfound/mf-media-engine-dxgi-manager) attribute.